# channel set permissions and move_to channel

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am using [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to make a discord [`Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#client). I am using [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) to see if the [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState) of a member changes.

If a member is inside a specific [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel), I want the client to create a new voice channel, using the member's username as the name of the channel, and move the member inside that new voice channel. Here is my code:

```py
import discord, asyncio

app = discord.Client()

@app.event
async def on_voice_state_update(user_name, user_id, after):
    name2 = str(user_name)
    ch = app.get_channel(660213767820410918)
    guild = app.get_guild(660213767820410893)
    member = str(user_id)
    if after.channel == ch:
        await guild.create_voice_channel(name=(name2+'`s Room'), category=guild.get_channel(660213767820410908) ,user_limit=99 ,overwrites=(user_name ,{'manage_channels': True}))
        await guild.member.move_to(channel, reason=None)
```

This doesn't work. Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of errors.

First of all, the event [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) accepts three parameters, which are [`member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member), [`before`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState) and [`after`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState) instead of `user_name`, `user_id` and `after`.

When you used the [`guild.create_voice_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_voice_channel) function, you did not pass a proper dictionary and you forgot to assign `channel` to the newly created channel (that is why `channel` was undefined).

Finally, you should have used [`member.move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to) instead of `guild.member.move_to` as `guild.member` is undefined.

```py
import discord, asyncio

app = discord.Client()

@app.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    username = str(member)
    guild = app.get_guild(660213767820410893)
    ch = guild.get_channel(660213767820410918)

    if after.channel == ch:
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(
                  name = (username+"'s Room"),
                  category = guild.get_channel(660213767820410908),
                  user_limit = 99,
                  overwrites = {member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(manage_channels=True)}
        )
        await member.move_to(channel)
```

Finally please check that the app is in the server and has the [`Move Members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.move_members) permission on the server, otherwise [`member.move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to) will throw a [`discord.Forbidden`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Forbidden) error.